# AWS Lambda Layer Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyarrow.lib'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, parquet, pyarrow

I followed the following steps to create a layer to use in my AWS Lambda function.

1. Downloaded the pyarrow library to python folder using the following command

   pip install pyarrow==5.0.0 -t python
2. Then recursively zipped the python folder

   zip -r pyarrow.zip python/
3. Uploaded the zipped file using the AWS Lambda UI and successfully created a layer.
4. Added the layer to my lambda function.

However when I try to import pyarrow I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyarrow.lib'
```

I downloaded the the zip file. I can see the pyarrow folder in it. But for some reason Lambda can't find the pyarrow. Any suggestions or advice where I could have made a mistake?

Comment: Double-check that you followed the [packaging instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-package-with-dependency).

Answer (score 1):

Assume your code is in "function_code" folder in some path

1. pip install pyarrow==5.0.0 -t function_code/
2. cd function_code
3. zip -r funcition_code.zip * (you should not zip the folder but only its contents)
4. Upload the zip

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to resolve it by reading the medium article in the accepted answer for this question: [numpy error when importing pandas with AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697824/numpy-error-when-importing-pandas-with-aws-lambda)

So, I used the `*manylinux1_x86_64.whl` package for pyarrow instead of numpy and pandas